# Prove that the graphs $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

[image]

Let $G$ be the graph on the left and $H$ be the graph on the right.

**For $G$:**

number of edges: $9$

number of vertices: $6$

degree sequence: $3,3,3,3,3,3$

**For $H$:**

number of edges: $9$

number of vertices: $6$

degree sequence: $3,3,3,3,3,3$

I am having trouble proving these two are not isomorphic. I see $4$-cycles in $H$ but not in $G$.

Comment: Please exhibit a cycle of odd length in $H$. There are none.

Comment: Was a reply to someone else's comment that they have since deleted.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to see they *are* in fact *isomorphic*.  Each is the complete bipartite graph on two sets of three vertices each: the sets being the upper and lower vertices on the left, and sets of every other vertex on the ones arranged on a hexagon.